# ANOVA with interactions

Tags: anova, interaction, interpretation

I've learned that ANOVA is simply a t-test but can compare more than 2 groups. However, I recently saw someone including an interaction term in an ANOVA test. What exactly is this doing? Do I interpret the ANOVA with Interaction effects the same way as a regular ANOVA? (simply compare the means of the groups, where one of those groups is the interaction term)?